# Trying to do a perfect sed replacement

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to do a sed replacement which I am currently doing with two commands. I can't figure out how to combine the two commands together so that it replaces the words correctly in one go.

My role here is to append `sc_admin` to every place which has the words `admin` in there.

Below are all the combinations of words that I can think of:

```
access = read : [ admin ], write : [ admin, power ]
access = read : [ security_pan_power ], write : [ security_pan_power ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, wis_master, wis_read_only, wis_web ]
access = read : [ admin ]
access = read : [ admin, somerole ], write : [ admin, power ]
```

So currently I am using 2 sed commands to do replacements

```
sed -e '/\bsc_admin\b/b' -e '/admin/ s/ *]/, sc_admin ]/' infile
```

replaces the word admin in the read portion correctly but does not replace the word admin in the write portion.

for example

```
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power ]
access = read : [ security_pan_power ], write : [ security_pan_power ]
access = read : [ *, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, wis_master, wis_read_only, wis_web ]
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, somerole, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power ]
access = read : [ defadmin, somerole, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power ]
```

while

```
 sed -e '/\bsc_admin\b/b' -e '/admin/ s/ *] *$/, sc_admin ]/'
```

command appends the word admin in the write portion correctly while it does not do anything to the read portion.

```
access = read : [ admin ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ security_pan_power ], write : [ security_pan_power ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, wis_master, wis_read_only, wis_web, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, somerole ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ defadmin, somerole ], write : [ admin, power ]
```

So currently I am running one command and then I am running the second command to fix the files. Is there a fool-proof way to combine the commands so that I get the proper output?

This is the actual output that I desire:

```
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ security_pan_power ], write : [ security_pan_power ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, wis_master, wis_read_only, wis_web, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, somerole, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
```

Comment: Should we assume you are using GNU `sed`? If you are using Linux the answer is yes.

Comment: i am running this on my Mac. is that not GNU sed? i am only a few months into learning bash scripting. so im still a noob.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a noob! We were all noobs once. And no, that probably means you don't have GNU sed, I was just surprised to see the \b working, I thought that was GNU-only, but I may well be wrong. Is the order of the entries inside each [ ] important? Isn't it enough to just do `sed 's/\badmin\b/&, sc_admin/g' infile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following with `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/\(\[ admin[^]]*\) /\1, sc_admin /g' file 
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ security_pan_power ], write : [ security_pan_power ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, wis_master, wis_read_only, wis_web, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ admin, somerole, sc_admin ], write : [ admin, power, sc_admin ]
```

---

- `\(\[ admin[^]]*\)`  capture the string '[ admin<every character that is not a ] and a final space>. For this we enclose the capture between `\(...\)`, and use `[^]]*` to select characters that are not(`^`) ']'.
- `\1, sc_admin`  substitute with the captured group (`\1`) and append ', sc_admin'.

Comment: spot on. it will take me a day to completely understand the command but this works exactly the way i want. I am still new to bash but i will figure out the whole command. Thanks.

Comment: @ranjitabraham I added an explanation, I hope it helps, if in doubt just tell me.